# Firefox: Opening a set of tabs each in specific windows from the command line

Tags: command-line, firefox

I would like to write a script that will set up everything I need to get to work, among other things, that includes opening my usual set of URLs just the I like them (i.e. inbox.google.com and reddir.com in the first window, whatsapp and slack in another)

looking in `firefox -h` showed me a way to open a tab from the command line, but without a way to determine to which window it goes, so when I create a new tab from the command line, it will always go to the first window created, which is a problem if I want 5 tabs in one window and 2 in the other.

Is there a way to get Firefox to open a tab in another window (giving it a window identifier somehow, combining with a plugin, maybe even a hacky way to write the command sequence?)

---

NOTE: Whatever the solution maybe, it needs to be entirely scriptable, because I want to be able to combine it with unrelated commands (like also opening my IDE, a terminal window and so on)

Comment: Don't know if this works but maybe you could try this:
- Open first window
- Open tabs you want in first window
- Open second window
- Open tabs you want in second window
Hopefully the commands to open tabs goes to the newest created window. If so this should work.

Comment: I have tried that one just before posting this question. After opening the second window, any additional tabs are still created in the first one

Comment: Firefox doesn't seem to have this functionality.. Tested the same thing with Chrome. This is what I found. `chrome.exe -new-window url1 url2 url3` gives a new window with tabs for each of the given urls. It doesn't matter where you place the "new-window" command (first, last, in the middle etc). Whenever it is present all urls in the command will be passed to the new window.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script which loads multiple instances of Firefox using the `-P` and `-no-remote` flags, each with a different profile name.

For example, in Powershell:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" '-P "Profile 1" -no-remote'

Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" '-P "Profile 2" -no-remote'

Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" '-P "Profile 3" -no-remote'
```

Use the following process:

- Open the tabs and load the URL for each tab in the current window
- Change the startup settings to `Show your windows and tabs from last time`
- Close the window
- Repeat for each window
- Rerun the script to verify

> When Firefox is running and you try to open another Firefox process, a new window is opened instead, in the already running process. You can use the -no-remote command line option to start a new Firefox process that is invisible to the first process. [1] By using -no-remote along with the -P option to select a different profile, you can open multiple instances of Firefox at the same time, using separate profiles. [2] Selecting a different profile from the one used in the first process is necessary because profiles are "locked" when in use.

**References**

- [Using multiple profiles - Firefox - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_multiple_profiles_-_Firefox)
- [Opening a new instance of your Mozilla application with another profile - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_your_Mozilla_application_with_another_profile)
- [Restore previous session - Configure when Firefox shows your most recent tabs and windows | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session)
- [PowerShell.exe Command Line Help | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6)
- [When to Quote in PowerShell - Simple Talk](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/when-to-quote-in-powershell/)
- [PowerShell Issue #1995: Arguments for external executables aren't correctly escaped](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995)